# Should I deploy the **.css.map/**.js.map files for a react web site?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm playing with `create-react-app` and have run:

`npm run build`

after that I got

> The build folder is ready to be deployed.

But when I checked my build folder, I see `main.**.css.map` and `main.**.js.map` files inside.

I guess there are for debug only, should I deploy them as well?

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't have to deploy them if you don't want to debug your app in production. Those are source map files and as you guessed using those files you can see where the error is coming from. Without them, it will be seen as coming from your bundled, minified, uglified file.